# Error Additional property conntainer_name is not allowed or start MySQL in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I need help.
I'm trying to upload a MySql container to Docker but I'm getting the following error:

```
rodri@home MINGW64 ~/eclipse/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/GestaoVendas
$ docker-compose up -d
validating C:\Users\rodri\eclipse\Desenvolvimento\Projetos\GestaoVendas\docker-compose.yml: services.mysql Additional property conntainer_name is not allowed
```

My docker configuration file looks like this:

```
version: '3.8'

services:

mysql: 
 image: mysql:8.0.22
 conntainer_name: mysql
 environment:
   MYSQL_USER: gvendas
   MYSQL_PASSWORD: gvendas
   MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
   MYSQL_DATABASE: gvendas_db
 volume:
  - .dbdata:/var/lib/mysql
 ports:
   - 3306:3306
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baV83.png)

The version I got from this site:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-versioning/

Comment: `conntainer_name` is spelled wrong, there is an extra n

Comment: It still didn't work. Same mistake

` rodri@home MINGW64 ~/eclipse/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/GestaoVendas (main)
$ docker-compose up -d
validating C:\Users\rodri\eclipse\Desenvolvimento\Projetos\GestaoVendas\docker-compose.yml: services.mysql Additional property volume is not allowed`

Comment: `volumes:` needs to be plural.

Comment: It worked!!!! Thanks!!!!